# What's reason behind the assassination of John Boone in KSR's Red Mars?

Tags: kim-stanley-robinson, mars-trilogy, red-mars

No spoilers in the question, given that it's the first thing the book narrates.

We know the reasons the guy who did the deed thought he had to do it.

> Selim killed him because he was convinced by Chalmers that Boone would be unfair to Arabs during the negotiations of the renewal of the treaty, if I'm correct

But I'm not really convinced about the motives of his instigator.

> Red Mars portrays Chalmers as an ambitious, manipulative man; he supposedly ceded his place in the first mission to Boone thinking that the first man would be too highly exposed to radiation to be considered for the follow-up *real* colonization mission, in which he himself would be the most important man. Boone got sent to colonize Mars anyway, destroying his plans because as *The Mars Daddy* he had more street cred. Furthermore, he later *stole his girl*. So, is that really it?

After all,

> He didn't have much desire left for Maya (he hated that she had any remaining effect on him) and Boone didn't seem much of a threat for the upcoming renegotiation deals either (Boone's position was highly unrealistic and unworkable). Why kill him? Just out of spite? Sounds risky and pointless.

-- nachokb

Comment: I finished reading this again last night and I can't come up with any better motivation than power and jealousy that you've already identified. There seems to be a lack of specific trigger event, just lots of little stuff building up over a lifetime.